# Can an address be assigned to a variable in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, addressof, address-operator

Is it possible to assign a variable the address you want, in the memory?

I tried to do so but I am getting an error as "Lvalue required as left operand of assignment".

```
int main() {
  int i = 10;
  &i = 7200;
  printf("i=%d address=%u", i, &i);
}
```

What is wrong with my approach?
Is there any way in C in which we can assign an address we want, to a variable?

Comment: Wait, so do you want to move `i` in memory to address 7200?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Yes!absolutely i want the variable i to be stored at 7200.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly.
You can do this though : int* i = 7200;
.. and then use i (ie. *i = 10) but you will most likely get a crash. This is only meaningful when doing low level development - device drivers, etc... with known memory addreses.

Comment: In order to _safely_ use specific address for your variable, use linker command file. (See answer below for details.)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are on an x86-type processer on a modern operating system, it is not possible to write to aribtray memory locations; the CPU works in concert with the OS to protect memory so that one process cannot accidentally (or intentionally) overwrite another processes' memory. Allowing this would be a security risk (see: buffer overflow). If you try to anyway, you get the 'Segmentation fault' error as the OS/CPU prevents you from doing this.

For technical details on this, you want to start with [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode), and [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Instead, you ask the OS to give you a memory location you can write to, using `malloc`. In this case, the OS kernel (which is generally the only process that *is* allowed to write to arbitrary memory locations) finds a free area of memory and allocates it to your process. The allocation process also marks that area of memory as belonging to your process, so that you can read it and write it.

However, a different OS/processor architecture/configuration could allow you to write to an arbitrary location. In that case, this code would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  int *ptr;
  ptr = (int*)7000;
  *ptr = 10;
  printf("Value: %i", *ptr);
}
```

Comment: It is important to note that you can request the OS change a memory page's permissions to allow you to write to it (or execute from it, or both). This is still within the process' virtual memory map, but allows you to write to many more locations. This is fundamental to how many JIT-compiling systems function.

Comment: This will possibly lead to seg-fault.

Answer (score 3):

C language provides you with no means for "attaching" a name to a specific memory address. I.e.  you cannot tell the language that a specific variable name is supposed to refer to a lvalue located at a specific address. So, the answer to your question, as stated, is "no". End of story.

Moreover, formally speaking, there's no alternative portable way to work with specific numerical addresses in C. The language itself defines no features that would help you do that.

However, a specific implementation might provide you with means to access specific addresses. In a typical implementation, converting an integral value `A`to a pointer type creates a pointer that points to address `A`. By dereferencing such pointer you can access that memory location.

Answer (score 1):

Not portably. But some compilers (usually for the embedded world) have extensions to do it.

For example on IAR compiler (here for MSP430), you can do this:

```
static const char version[] @ 0x1000 = "v1.0";
```

This will put object `version` at memory address `0x1000`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in the windows system with mingw64 setup in visual studio code tool, here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *c;
    c = (int *)0x000000000061fe14; // Allocating the address 8-bit with respect to your CPU arch.
    *c = NULL; // Initializing the null pointer for allocated address
    *c = 0x10; // Assign a hex value (you can assign integer also without '0x')
    printf("%p\n",c); // Prints the address of the c pointer variable
    printf("%x\n",*c); // Prints the assigned value 0x10 -hex 
}
```

It is tested with mentioned environment. Hope this helps Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

No.

Even if you could, 7200 is not a pointer (memory address), it's an int, so that wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why. I'm not sure why myself, but I've got a general idea that it might have something to do with virtual to real addressing.

Comment: >> "7200 is not a pointer (memory address), it's an int, so that wouldn't work anyway" : Disagree. That's why it has to be casted. & then it does work.

Comment: Only for weird values of "work". It's not standard C. The language does not guarantee that (char *)7200 will do anything sensible.

Comment: It's very much standard practise in embedded systems.

Comment: See this question for example of casting an integer to pointer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763006/const-volatile-pointer-function-argument

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no way to determine which address a variable will have. But as a last hope for you, there is something called "pointer", so you can modify a value on address `7200` (although this address will probably be inaccessible):

```
int *i = (int *)7200;
*i = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ldscript/linker command file. This will however, assign at link time, not run time.

Linker command file syntax depends largely on specific compiler. So you will need to google for linker command file, for your compiler.

Approximate pseudo syntax would be somewhat like this:

```
In linker command file:
.section start=0x1000 lenth=0x100 myVariables
In C file:
#pragma section myVariables
int myVar=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, maybe possible with compiler extensions. You could however access memory at an address you want (if the address is accessible to your process):

```
int addr = 7200;
*((int*)addr) = newVal;
```

Comment: This will possibly lead to seg-fault.

Comment: Thanks, that's why i mentioned: "(if the address is accessible to your process)"

Answer (score 0):

I think ***'&'*** in ***&a*** evaluates the address of i at the compile time which i think is a virtual address .So it is not a Lvalue according to your compiler. Use pointer instead