# How to preserve RAM cell from being used

Tags: c, gcc, arm, gnu

I use GNU for ARM and want to define some cell in RAM memory space as following:

```
#define FOO_LOCATION 0x20000000
#define foo (*((volatile uint32_t *) FOO_LOCATION ))
```

My question is - if such declaration will prohibit usage of the cell with `FOO_LOCATION` address in stack or heap? What address preffered to avoid memory fragmentation?

---

Update

I want to place some variable at a certain memory address and access it after watchdog reset. I guess that if i will declare it as usual

```
uint32_t foo;
```

it will have another physical location after reset. Also i read a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558995/can-an-address-be-assigned-to-a-variable-in-c) where said that most probably there is no such way to declare variable adddress. And i have idea to tell the GNU not to use some memory address. As for example special registers are not used by custom variables.

---

Update 2

In addition to previous definitions i added section to linker script

```
SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x20000000
  .fooSection :
  {
    *(.fooSection)
    . = 0x04 /* size = 4 bytes */
  } 
  /* other placements follow here... */
}
```

Comment: That's not a declaration. That's just a macro, which is basically a fancy search/replace command in your source code.

Comment: No, such declaration will not prohibit anything about stack or heap. Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. Please also clarify "What address preffered to avoid memory fragmentation" - I didn't understand that question.

Comment: thanks, i did an update to the topic @anatolyg

Comment: seems i found useful post which tells that the variable should be placed into a section https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/11/01/defining-variables-at-absolute-addresses-with-gcc/

Comment: It seems that you found the answer to your question. If yes, you might want to format it as an answer (though it might be too much trouble for you). If not, please specify what the question is.

Comment: Yes, seems i found the answer. Going to do some hardware tests. Thanks a lot.